# How to sync music videos when iCloud Music Library is enabled?

Tags: ios, itunes, icloud, apple-music

I've just notice that after I subscribe to Apple Music (and enabled iCloud Music Library that comes with it), music videos in my iTunes Library are no longer syncing. That is whenever I added a new music video (manually by adding the file to iTunes and setting the type to `Music Video`), it no longer shows up in my iOS device – even after I plug it in.

I know that the music videos are [not eligible to sync via iCloud](https://support.apple.com/en-sg/HT203564). However, that said, plugging-in the device via USB should sync those that are not eligible for cloud syncing, right?

The question is, how can I add those non-iCloud music videos in my iTunes library to my iOS device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got off the phone with Apple I have the same problem. according to the guy i spoke with Apple Music will only recognize music bought from iTunes. it part of their Digital Music Rights or some BS of that nature. im taking all of my music videos and i changed their setting to Tv Show. and re-sync with computer and everything is back

Answer (score -1):

I set mine to movies and created a single title which would be the album name of all the music videos.